# Poincaré-Hopf index theorem for meromorphic differentials, Griffiths'

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

In Griffiths' Introduction to Algebraic Curves is prooven that if $ω$ is a meromorphic differential on a compact Riemann surface $C$, then $\sum_{p\in C}v_p(\omega)=-\chi(C)$.

But by definition we have thah, if $\omega=\{(U_i,z_i,f_i(z_i)dz_i)\}$ and $p\in U_i$, then $v_p(\omega)=v_p(f_i)$ and since we know that $\sum_{p\in C}v_p(f)=0$, putting $w=f(z)dz$ we could have that $\chi(C)=0$ always.

What am I missing?

[$(U_i,z_i)$ are the complex charts and $f_i(z_i)dz_i$ the representation of $\omega$ in coordinates in $U_i$]

Comment: Those $f_i$'s don't glue together to give a globally defined meromorphic function, hence you don't have $\sum v_p(f_i) = 0$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but what if I start from a meromorphic function $f$ defined on $C$ and then I consider for example $\omega=df=\{(U_i,z_i,\dfrac{df_i(z_i)}{dz_i} dz_i)\}$? don't I have that $\dfrac{df_i(z_i)}{dz_i}=f'|_{U_i}$

Comment: $f'$ is not a function on $C$ though if $C$ is non-trivial.

Comment: With $\omega = f(z) \, dz$ you will *not* have $v_p(\omega) = v_p(f)$ for all $p$. Specifically, this will fail wherever $z$ is not a local coordinate, i.e., wherever $z$ has a pole or takes on a value with multiplicity $> 1$. For instance, try with $C = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ the Riemann sphere and $\omega = dz$, where $z$ is the usual coordinate on $\mathbb{C}$. You'll see that there is a problem with your argument at $\infty$, where $z$ has a pole.